# Laptop lenovo doesn't find webcamera

Tags: thinkpad, integrated-camera

I have this [Lenovo Thinkpad](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Lenovo-Thinkpad-T520-Notebook.51596.0.html)

The problem is that I can't use built-in camera. It is just like there is no camera. Driver is installed and when I switch on laptop on, the camera LED blink once.
When I go on Skype for example I don't have camera. On other hand the microphone which is built in with webcam work fine.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Can you try pressing FN + F6 - this appears to be the shortcut to the camera and I wonder if this does anything?

Comment: I saw this also but doesn't help. No idea what to do more.

Comment: You say "you switch on laptop the camera blinks once" - what does that mean?

Comment: @DaveRook u know when you switch on your PC how all lamps(CD, CPU, Camera, etc) blink once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying FN+F6 didn't work for you (but I leave it on in case it helps others who find this post).

Some suggest that the Lenovo Easy Capture software runs at start up and this 'locks' the camera. If you can, disable it at start up by using [msconfig](http://www.netsquirrel.com/msconfig/index.html)   (although be careful if you use facial recognition to log in as I don't know if this will cause an error)

Comment: I'll try in few minutes. Will let you know for the result.

Comment: i checked again FN+F6, in msconfig I don't have such a think like Lenovo Easy Capture.

Comment: Is there any software associated with the CAM (by Lenovo)? If, uninstall it (but make sure you can re-install original program)

Comment: I didn't find such a software. There is only one driver available for this model Lenovo T520 [Driver Camera](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/SCANNER-Digital-CAMERA-WEBCAM/Lenovo/Lenovo-ThinkPad-T520-Webcam-Driver-1101147-11111013.shtml)

Comment: In BIOS i switch to Enable - Fn button. But doesn't seem to work .. is same on disable and enable.

Comment: In that case I suggest you contact Lenovo direct.

Comment: Still waiting for responde from Lenovo support.